# Removing Square Google Pay from Certain Product Pages in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, square

Is there a way I can remove google/apple pay from certain products on my woocommerce store? Payments are handled by Square.

```
add_filter( 'wc_square_display_digital_wallet_on_pages', function( $pages ) {
    return array(
        /* 'product', // Don't show Apple Pay and Google Pay on product pages */
        'cart',
        'checkout',
    );
}, 10, 1 );
```

The code above allows me to remove the button from all product pages, however I'd like to only remove from certain pages using their product id's.

Is this possible at all?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can probably try this and let me know if this worked:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'remove_square_button' ) ) {
    function remove_square_button() {
        global $post;
        $productsToExclude = array(12, 123, 1234); //put all product ids here where you want to hide it.
        //check if single product page and its the id we want to exclude
        if ( is_product() && in_array($post->ID, $productsToExclude)) {
            add_filter( 'wc_square_display_digital_wallet_on_pages', function( $pages ) {
                return array(
                    'cart',
                    'checkout',
                );
            }, 10, 1 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_square_button' );
```

This should hide the button on single product pages based on the IDs you mention in that array.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately it didn't seem to work

Comment: Did you added the IDs of the products in the array?

Comment: Yes I did, but it still left the Google pay buttons on all products.

Comment: This removes the button. The Square .js and .css code remains and are loaded on every product page. Is there a way to remove that as well?